# I am getting the error : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). What could be the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, mapreduce

Im running a mapreduce job, but it keeps failing saying missing input. Unfortunately its not showing where its missing either

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
import re

class flight_combination(MRJob):
    def steps(self):
        return [MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_1,reducer=self.reducer_1)]

    def mapper_1(self,_,value):
        group1 = {}
        group2 = {}
        parts = value.split(",")
        destination = parts[0]
        origin = parts[1]
        count = parts[2]
        group1[destination] = {'Origin': origin, 'count': count}
        group2[origin] = {'Destination':destination,'count':count}
        yield group1
        yield group2

    def reducer_1(self,key,value):
        g1,g2 = data
        for key1 in g1:
            for key2 in g2:
                if g1[key1]['Origin'] == g2[key2]['Destination']:
                    total = int(g1[key1]['count'])*int(g2[key2]['count'])
                yield (key1,key2,total)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        flight_combination.run()
```

Following is the error:

```
`File "wd.py", line 35, in <module>
   flight_combination.run()
…...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 536, in run_mapper
    for out_key, out_value in mapper(key, value) or ():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `run` method of the object type `flight_combination` is **expecting 2 arguments, but provided with 1 argument**. ( Python by default takes `self` as the first argument for methods invoked on object)

To fix this -

1. as the method `run` is defined in the parent class, go through its definition and pass the other argument.
2. Override the `run` method by redefining it `flight_combination` class and provide your logic.